# Changing between User models in a JavaFX App

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

In my current JavaFX app, there can be different users which have different data relating to them. In different parts of the app labels, tables, graphs etc are bound to observable properties in the user class.

The problem comes when changing users. The bindings are still bound to the previous user. Is there a better way to update this other than rebinding all the parts of the UI on a user change?

The user data is stored in a DataManager class which is passed to all controllers, so they have access to the same data.

DataManager example:

```
public class DataManager {

    private ObservableList<User> userList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    private User currentUser;

   public void addUser(String name, int age, double height, double weight) {
        User newUser = new User(name, age, height, weight);
        try {
            DatabaseWriter.createDatabase();
            newUser.setId(UserDBOperations.insertNewUser(newUser));
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        userList.add(newUser);
    }

    public void deleteUser(User user) {
        try {
            DatabaseWriter.createDatabase();
            UserDBOperations.deleteExistingUser(user.getId());
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        userList.remove(user);
    }

    public updateCurrentUser();

    public changeUser();
}
```

Example User class:

```
public class User {

    private int id;
    private StringProperty name;
    private IntegerProperty age;
    private DoubleProperty height;
    private DoubleProperty weight;
    private DoubleProperty bmi;
    private DoubleProperty totalDistance;

    private ObservableList<Event> eventList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
```

Is there a better way to use model data that would work better in this situation? I can provide more code/app context if it would help in answering.

Thanks

EDIT 1:

```
public class ParentController {

    private DataManager dataManager = new DataManager();
    private ChildController childController1;
    private ChildController childController2;


    public void initializeChild() {
        childController1.setDataManager(dataManager);
        childController2.setDataManager(dataManager);
        // Controllers for different FXML Files
        //
    }
}

public class ChildController {

    /*  Child controller has elements which need data 
        from the DataManager
    */

    private DataManager dataManager;

    public void setDataManager(DataManager dataManager) {
        this.dataManager = dataManager;
    }
}
```

The main problem I'm trying to overcome is how to keep the database, the model stored in memory, and all the different pages in sync with the same data model. Any suggestions or resources that could point me in the right direction would be great.

EDIT 2: Added more context about database connection

Comment: Could you provide more context for *stored in a DataManager class which is passed to all controllers* . First guess is that all controllers are calling the methods from a Singleton `DataManager` or are you passing different instances ?

Comment: Another question that comes to my mind: are you filling the User class directly from backend data (e.g. database or similar) or is there another data transfer object between them?

Comment: Data is inputted through the UI and is saved in persistent storage in a SQLite database. I'll update the question to include more about the DataManager

Comment: I've added some context about the DataManager.

Comment: Wherever your currentUser is stored, you can make that class itself an Observable (I guess it is the DataManager) and let the Views displaying the user information listen to the change events.

Comment: Could you just re-create the controller/view with the new user model, and the replace the old view with the new one? It should be quick enough that you don't see it.

Comment: @Alex I thought of doing this but wasn't sure if this would be considered poor practice or not.

Comment: @Adam I don't really know anything about JavaFX best practices, but that's how I'd do it anyway. It's simple, clean and I don't think it would cause bad performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply put, you must rebind the controls to display the new data.

When you bind a `TextProperty` to a `user.NameProperty`, for example, that binding is specific for that one `user` object. Even if you change the user, the binding is still pointing back to the original user.

One possible and simple solution is to use a Singleton class to store your selected `User`. This will allow the selected user to be visible to your entire application:

**User.java**

```
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;

public class User {

    private StringProperty username = new SimpleStringProperty();

    public User(String username) {
        this.username.set(username);
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username.get();
    }

    public StringProperty usernameProperty() {
        return username;
    }
}
```

**GlobalData.java**

```
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;

public class GlobalData {

    // Global property to hold the currently-selected user
    private ObjectProperty<User> selectedUser = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

    private static GlobalData ourInstance = new GlobalData();

    public static GlobalData getInstance() {
        return ourInstance;
    }

    private GlobalData() {
    }

    public User getSelectedUser() {
        return selectedUser.get();
    }

    public ObjectProperty<User> selectedUserProperty() {
        return selectedUser;
    }

    public void setSelectedUser(User selectedUser) {
        this.selectedUser.set(selectedUser);
    }
}
```

Now, in your UI controllers, you would just need to create a listener to watch for changes to the `selectedUser`. When the user changes, just rebind the UI elements in each controller.

Here is a simple MCVE to demonstrate:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.Random;

public class Main extends Application {

    // The Label which holds the username value
    private Label lblUsername = new Label();

    // Grab a reference to the GlobalData singleton
    private GlobalData globalData = GlobalData.getInstance();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        // Create the initial sample User
        globalData.setSelectedUser(new User("User #1"));

        // Simple interface
        VBox root = new VBox(10);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        // HBox to hold the username display
        HBox hBox = new HBox(5);
        hBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        // Add the username labels to the HBox
        hBox.getChildren().addAll(
                new Label("Username:"),
                lblUsername
        );

        // Bind the Label to display the current selected user's username
        lblUsername.textProperty().bind(globalData.getSelectedUser().usernameProperty());

        // Here we use a listener on the the selectedUser property. When it changes, we
        // call the rebindUser() method to update the UI
        globalData.selectedUserProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            if (newValue != null) {
                rebindUser(newValue);
            }
        });

        // Add a button that just changes the selectedUser
        Button button = new Button("Change User");

        // Set the action for the button to change users
        button.setOnAction(this::changeUser);

        // Add the HBox and button to the root layout
        root.getChildren().addAll(hBox, button);

        // Show the Stage
        primaryStage.setWidth(400);
        primaryStage.setHeight(200);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void changeUser(ActionEvent event) {

        // Create a new user with a random # at the end
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int num = rnd.nextInt(50 + 2);

        globalData.setSelectedUser(new User("User #" + num));
    }

    // This method accepts a new User object and updates all the displayed bindings
    private void rebindUser(User newUser) {
        lblUsername.textProperty().unbind();
        lblUsername.textProperty().bind(newUser.usernameProperty());
    }
}
```

This produces the following output:

[image: Screenshot]

Clicking the button will create a random new user, update the `selectedUser` property of the `GlobalData` singleton, and the `Label` gets updated through the `rebindUser()` method.

Comment: Singletons are evil ... just saying ;)

Comment: @kleopatra - I keep hearing that, but I still find them quite useful in cases like this. Then again, I'm an amateur myself so who knows? :)

Comment: @Zephyr Thanks, was exactly the kind of solution I was looking for.

Comment: and now another "amateur" did learn the wrong trick <g> no offense meant at any of you @Adam :)

Comment: Instead of just saying this solution is wrong and evil, can you explain why? Or provide the right solution?

Comment: @kleopatra - It's pretty crappy to tell someone their solution is a bad one when you don't explain why or attempt to provide a better solution yourself. Such comments also do nothing to add to the site's usefulness or help future readers. The OP asked for help and I provided a solution that works for them, that's all.

Comment: didn't say your answer is bad (the basic idea is good), just the means are suboptimal ;) There are millions of debates about the pros and cons of singletons .. if you are interested in learning, search the net ... if not *shrugs

Comment: I have used this `GlobalData` singleton pattern in my own application for a few years now and have had no trouble. For simple applications, I see nothing wrong with it. I've read up on several "cons" of using a Singleton, but none have been applicable in any situation I've come across just yet.

Comment: @kleopatra if you weren't going to use a Singleton, could you provide an example or links to examples of how you would do it?